# Javascript: is reading ES6 Map.size constant time?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, hashmap, ecmascript-6, time-complexity

Getting the size of an Object usually consists of iterating and counting, or Object.keys(obj).length which is also O(n). If I switch to Map, can I assume Map.size runs in O(1)?

I'm pretty new to Javascript, coming from the C++ world, and I was shocked I couldn't find a standard that specs the time complexity of all functions provided by the language.

Answer (score 2):

You can't rely on it except on implementations where you've examined the source code or proved it empirically. [The specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-get-map.prototype.size) shows that `Map.prototype.size` is a getter with looping logic:

> **get Map.prototype.size**
>
> Map.prototype.size is an accessor property whose set accessor function is **undefined**. Its get accessor function performs the following steps:
>
> 1. Let *M* be the **this** value.
> 2. If *Type*(*M*) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 3. If *M* does not have a [[MapData]] internal slot, throw a TypeError exception.
> 4. Let *entries* be the List that is the value of *M*'s [[MapData]] internal slot.
> 5. Let *count* be 0.
> 6. For each Record {[[Key]], [[Value]]} *p* that is an element of *entries*
>
>    - If *p*.[[Key]] is not empty, set *count* to *count*+1.
> 7. Return *count*.

But implementations are free to optimize provided the semantics of `size` are unchanged.